# Javafx clear stroking rectangle

Tags: canvas, javafx, stroke

I am new to javaFX and want to try a simple application.
I have an application with a Canvas and I draw a rectangle, but I can't erase it's border properly.

Here is how I handle it :

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

g.setFill(colorBackground);
g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
g.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
g.strokeRect(200, 200, 10, 10);
g.setStroke(colorBackground);
g.strokeRect(200, 200, 10, 10);
```

But I still have a greyish rectangle instead of just nothing. I don't understand why I have this.
Maybe I use Canvas wrong or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `colorBackground` grey? Then the issue is that you're not erasing anything. To clear the canvas, use [`GraphicsContext#clearRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clearRect-double-double-double-double-). Then you can erase your rectangle (or the whole canvas) like so:

```
g.clearRect(200, 200, 10, 10);
```

Note that this will clear the desired rectangle with a transparent color, not to your specified `colorBackground`. To emulate a colored background, you can place an opaque `Node` (such as another `Canvas`) behind your `Canvas`, so that the transparency makes that colored "background" node visible.

Comment: My background colour is White actually, I tried with clearRect but without success.

Comment: It worked with the background canvas though, thank you !